# Next.js import bundle size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to import components based on variable. My point is to import just the one I want to reduce bundle size.

First Case:

```
 const componentMapONE = {
  'customers': dynamic(() => import('../../../pages/customers'), {
              loading: () => <FallbackSpinner />,
              ssr: false
            }),
 'brands': dynamic(() => import('../../../pages/brands'), {
              loading: () => <FallbackSpinner />,
              ssr: false
            }),  
// .... others hardcoded manually, or generated with logic doesn't matter same result
};

const importPromises = (componentNames: string[]) => {
  return componentNames.map(name => {
    const loadComponent = componentMap[name];
    if (!loadComponent) {
      throw new Error(`Component ${name} not found`);
    }
    return loadComponent;
  });
};
```

In this case I import from a map, that generated from logic or hardcoded.

Result: its importing all the hardcoded imports(6gb ram usage). Even when I don't call importPromises function. At the end of the day application runs without error.

Second Case:

```
 // with variable... even when child is null

const importPromises = (componentUrls: string[]) => {
  return componentUrls.map((child: string) => {
    return dynamic(() => import(`../../../pages/${child}`), {
      loading: () => <FallbackSpinner />,
      ssr: false
    })
  })
}

// without variable...

const importPromises = (componentUrls: string[]) => {
  return componentUrls.map((child: string) => {
    return dynamic(() => import(`../../../pages`), {
      loading: () => <FallbackSpinner />,
      ssr: false
    })
  })
}
```

In this case I import with changing path with variable.
Result: Even when child is null, it imports all the pages(6.5gb ram usage). At the end of the day application runs without error.

Third Case:

```
 // with just string
 
 const importPromises = (componentUrls: string[]) => {
      return componentUrls.map((child: string) => {
        return dynamic(() => import(`../../../pages/customers`), {
          loading: () => <FallbackSpinner />,
          ssr: false
        })
      })
    }
```

In this case I import with just string without variable.
Result: Only customers page can be run, but ram usage is: 3.2gb which is lower.

Conculsion:

I know that next/dynamic doesn't work with variabled paths, thats why I also tried First Case. Here I got confused, I cannot see a valuable use case for using next/dynamic. Or I am using it wrong. Either when I import normal without next/dynamic or with next/dynamic, I got same result.

So I want to ask what next/dynamic actually does ?

Thanks.

This asked many where but still I couldn't find a  solution for me.

Edit: With bundle size I mean the RAM usage at next dev. Which is next-server

[image: Ram Usage:]